# Return html table from PHP using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going crazy trying to figure out how to display a table in a div tag after a user selects a select option.

JQuery/AJAX

```
$('#months').change(function() {

                  var month_sent = $('#months option:selected').text();

                  $.ajax ({
                      type: "GET",
                      dataType: 'text',
                      url: "db_connect.php",
                      data: "dept_sent=" + dept_sent + "&month_sent=" + month_sent + "&year_sent=" + year_sent,
                      success: function(data) {
                          $('#incident_table').html(data);
                      },
                      error: function() {
                        alert("Error!");
                      }

                  });
              });
```

PHP

```
  if ($dept && year && $month) {
      $query = "SELECT date,dept,area_name,ticket,description,resolution FROM incidents WHERE (dept = '$dept') AND (YEAR(date) = '$year') AND (MONTH(date) = '$month')";
      $query_image = "SELECT image_content FROM images WHERE dept_name = '$dept' AND year = '$year' AND month = '$month'";

      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $result_image = mysql_query($query_image);

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         // foreach ($row as $value) {
              $incident .= '<tr><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td>'.$row['dept'].'</td><td>'.$row['area_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['ticket'].'</td><td>'.$row['description'].'</td><td>'.$row['resolution'].'</td></tr>';
          //}
      }
      echo $incident;
  }
```

All i need to do is be able to display the table inside of the "incidents" div tag

Edit:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width:310px; height: 310px;" name="incidents" id="incidents">
      <table id="incident_table">
      </table>
  </div>
```

Please help! :(

Comment: Does the PHP side return the expected output?

Comment: echo '<table>'.$incident.'</table>';

Comment: be shure you are not alowing SQL injection using not escaped variables

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a **$** before **year** in the first line in PHP

change this line:
`if ($dept && year && $month) {`

to this:
`if ($dept && $year && $month) {`

Try to run the PHP file alone first to check it is working properly.

Comment: in this case `year` evaluate as `true`

Comment: Oppps didn't see that.  Thank you for the catch!  However, it still seems to not return the correct values back to the JQuery

Comment: This is kind of embarrassing.

     `$query_image = "SELECT image_content FROM images WHERE dept_name = '$dept' AND year = '$year' AND month = '$month'";`

I had to change the above to:

 

    `$query_image = "SELECT image_content FROM images WHERE dept_name = '$dept' AND year = '$year' AND MONTHNAME(date) = '$month'";`

So my SQL was to blame here

Comment: You need to change the query to the following:
$query_image = "SELECT image_content FROM images WHERE dept_name = '".$dept."' AND year = '".$year."' AND MONTHNAME(date) = '".$month."'";

Answer (score 0):

try change your php to this:

```
    if ($dept && year && $month) {
      print_r(1);exit;
      $query = "SELECT date,dept,area_name,ticket,description,resolution FROM incidents WHERE (dept = '$dept') AND (YEAR(date) = '$year') AND (MONTH(date) = '$month')";
      $query_image = "SELECT image_content FROM images WHERE dept_name = '$dept' AND year = '$year' AND month = '$month'";

      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $result_image = mysql_query($query_image);

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         // foreach ($row as $value) {
              $incident .= '<tr><td>'.$row['date'].'</td><td>'.$row['dept'].'</td><td>'.$row['area_name'].'</td><td>'.$row['ticket'].'</td><td>'.$row['description'].'</td><td>'.$row['resolution'].'</td></tr>';
          //}
      }
      echo $incident;
  } else print_r(0);exit;
```

then move print_r(1); command down until you catch the row with the problem

Answer (score 0):

insert the dynamic content into the `div` and not into the empty/incomplete `table` structure

```
 success: function(dataHTML) {
      $('#incidents').html(dataHTML);
 },
```

and in php

```
echo '<table id="incident_table">'.$incident.'</table>';
```

also read other comments about SQL injection and the missing $ on year

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I did try the above, but it still does not return the desired table inside of the div tag.  The PHP now seems to be in order.  Unsure on what is wrong

Comment: are you checking what is realy happening with firebug??? also is better to use  `data: {dept_sent: dept_sent, month_sent:month_sent, year_sent: year_sent}` but anyway I do not see how `year_sent` and `dept_sent` are asigned a value???